# Why does Visual Studio duplicate my menus and buttons? Persists after reinstall and profile wipe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Why does Visual Studio duplicate my menus and buttons?  This persists after reinstall and profile wipe. If I do `/resetsettings` it will work, but next time i load will have the same issue.

[image: Visual Studio]

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me

devenv.exe /resetuserdata

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- Shut down all instances of Visual Studio 2005
- Click Start, then choose Run....
- Type "devenv.exe /resetuserdata".

Answer (score 0):

Which extensions do you have installed?

Uninstall/Deactivate the extensions in reverse order of how much you can't live without them.
After each Uninstallation/Deactivation, close visual studio and reopen it, attempt to recreate the bug.

Once the bug disappears, reinstall all the ones you don't believe are a problem (one at a time).

Comment: HiI have no extensions installed and only the Resharper plugin xD

Answer (score -1):

Go to visual studio local user setting

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings
```

Remove all files from there.

I was able to solve my problem by using above steps.